# Netsuite bi-weekly formula

Tags: sql, oracle, netsuite

I'm trying to create a report for payroll that will sum all of the amounts between dates, however, I haven't found the correct SQL formula for it. For instance, I would like to say

case when {trandate} between 18/11/2019  and 1/12/2019 then 12/1/2019 else 0 end

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm really sure what you are trying to do with the `THEN 12/1/2019`.

If you are after a formula that only outputs the amount when the date is within the specified range, something like the below should do the trick.

```
CASE WHEN {trandate} BETWEEN TO_DATE('18/11/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('1/12/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY') THEN {amount} END
```